# Simplifying compound regular expressions using python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of compound and simple regular expressions that I need to simplify. Lets say `["(crazy|cute|funny)( \w+){0,5} cat", "I love( \w+){0,5} cats)"]`. I need to identify the ones which have a specific pattern. In example, I want to identify the ones twhich contains *or("|")*  and simplify them to a single pattern.

In the above example I want to convert `"(crazy|cute|funny)( \w+){0,5} cat` to `["crazy( \w+){0,5} cat", "cute( \w+){0,5} cat", "funny( \w+){0,5} cat"]`. I do not want to change `"I love( \w+){0,5} cats)"` cause it's a simple and not compound Regex.

I have came up with the following regex to identify such examples:

```
re = "\((\w+{1}\|){1,10}\w+{1}\)"
```

But it does not identify them. I am not sure what is wrong.

```
def sep_rules(search_list):
    new_query_list = list()
    for item in search_list:
        if "|" not in item:
            new_query_list.append(item)
        else:
            re = "\((\w+{1}\|){1,10}\w+{1}\)"
            print item 
            print re_search(item, re) # does not identify them correctly
```

Input data:

```
["(crazy|cute|funny)( \w+){0,5} cat", "I love( \w+){0,5} cats)"]
```

Expected output:

```
["crazy( \w+){0,5} cat" , "cute( \w+){0,5} cat" , "funny( \w+){0,5} cat" , "I love( \w+){0,5} cats)"]
```

Comment: This task is almost impossible to solve compeletely. To let it work on any pattern, you need to implement processing of regular expression by your own. To process this `((cute[^\\]?)|(cr(a|o)zy)|(f[uassds]nnyy?)( \w+){0,5} cat` you should rewrite half of `re` module.

Answer (score 0):

The error I get when compiling this pattern is "multiple repeat", referring to the pattern `\w+{1}`. This pattern indeed doesn't really make sense - you're basically applying two repeat directions (`+`, at least once, and `{1}`, exactly once) to the same expression `\w`.

If you wanted, you could put parentheses around it as in `(\w+){1}`, but you should be aware that having `{1}` anywhere in a regex is redundant in the first place; `<expression>{1}` is exactly equivalent to `<expression>`.

(Note: More generally, the problem you're trying to solve - minimization of regular expressions - is at least NP-hard, and certainly not solvable with another regular expression. You can at best apply a few very limited special cases.)

Comment: what I meant by that is exactly one word and then an  "|" operation.

Comment: @Moniba I understand (I think), but `\w+` would already match "exactly one word".

Comment: @Moniba The pattern `\w` matches a single word character, eg. `a`, `b`, etc. The pattern `\w+` matches any sequence of at least one word character, like `apple`. The pattern `(\w+){1}` *also* matches any sequence of at least one word character - "match X" and "match X exactly once" are the same thing. :)

Comment: but it would not match "|" right? that will solve the issue!

Comment: Correct - `|` is not matched by `\w`. Though the output of `re.findall()` applied to the first of your inputs will be `'cute|'`, because that's what is in the capture group. If you want to extract the whole `crazy|cute|funny` string (so it can then be split further), you should use `"\(((?:\w+\|){1,10}\w+)\)"`.